# How do i create/convert a css file using sass scss

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to create a file in sass and link it  notepad ++ i have tried  looking at videos on how to install it and use sass but they all are on mac.

Comment: http://sass-lang.com/install

Answer (score 18):

If you are a windows fan download [**Ruby Installer**](http://www.rubyinstaller.org/) and install it locally.

Go to `Start > All Programs > Ruby > Start Command Prompt with Ruby`

Then install SASS using `gem install sass` command.

You should now have installed sass, however you can check using `sass -v` command.

Now using command prompt change the directory to your sass directory and use following commands

```
# Convert Sass to SCSS
sass-convert style.sass style.scss

# Convert SCSS to Sass
sass-convert style.scss style.sass
```

To run Sass from the command line, just use

```
sass input.scss output.css
```

You can also tell Sass to watch the file and update the CSS every time the Sass file changes:

```
sass --watch input.scss:output.css
```

If you have a directory with many Sass files, you can also tell Sass to watch the entire directory:

```
sass --watch app/sass:public/stylesheets
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use "Npp Exec" extension (F6), with easier way:

use this execute commands to compile xxx.scss, generate & open the new xxx.css file

```
npp_save 
cmd /c "sass --update $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).scss:$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).css" 
$(NPP_DIRECTORY)\notepad++.exe $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).css 
npp_console 0
```